# How to save pipelined estimator in Keras?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, cross-validation

I am using Scikit Learn in Python where I pipelined KerasClassifier with StandardScaler().

The code is:

```
def create_baseline():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(11, input_dim=11, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(7, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_baseline, nb_epoch=150, batch_size=5)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)

estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', classifier))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)

results = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, Y, cv=kfold, verbose=1, fit_params={'mlp__callbacks':[tbCallBack]})
print("Result: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
```

How can I save the cross validation? Taking into consideration that I did not fit the classifier before, I need to save the result and then load it to make predictions.

Comment: `cross_val_score` will perform all operations on the clone of the supplied `pipeline` object. So your `pipeline` object is still unfitted after the cross_val_score.

Comment: So how can I fix that and save it when it is fitted? @VivekKumar

Comment: You need to call `pipeline.fit(X, Y)` fot that along with any fit_params you have. Then check [this documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) on saving scikit estimators. But for that I cant say, how it will internally handle the Keras object.

Comment: Upon further search, I found that you cannot save the keras object wrapped inside a scikit-learn object. See [github issue here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4274).  You will need to store the standardscaler and classifier separately. Use the joblib mentioned in above comment for `standardScaler` and `model.save()` for keras classifier.

Comment: How to use joblib on appended StandardScaler? and the model.save() isn't for KerasClassifier it is for the model in the create_baseline().

Comment: You can use pipeline.named_steps dict to get the esimators from pipeline. Use joblib.dump(pipeline.named_steps['standardize'], 'path_to_save_scaler.pkl') for the standardScalar.

Comment: Not possible to save the KerasClassifier due to supplied model not build until fit() is called. See the last comment of the linked github issue. You need to create a custom class for it.

Comment: I think I will change the code and return back to normal model without scikit learn, I have one question only, can I use Data Standardization on normal dataset? I mean using `standardized_X = preprocessing.scale(X)`
What is the difference compared to no standardization? what is the meaning of each attribute having a mean of zero and a standard deviation of one?